# Problems storing a matrix in Python

Tags: python, variables, matrix

So I have written a program in Python that takes a matrix from user's input and modifies it. From this modification I am able to pull out the inverse of the original matrix. To prove if the inverse is correct, I would like to do something like this:

```
matrix=input_from_the_user
matrix_untouched=input_from_the_user
... #act on **matrix** and turn it into its inverse, so that now **matrix** is no more 
    #the 
original: it is equal to its inverse
test=product_of_matrices(matrix,matrix_untouched)
print(test)
```

I would expect the output to be the identity matrix. It is not: it looks like the variable **matrix_untouched** turns into **matrix** even though I never touch it after defining it. I have tried to print **matrix_untouched** at different steps of the program. From the first modification I make on **matrix**, also **matrix_untouched** is modified in the same way. How can I keep its value unaltered?

Comment: Assignment like `matrix_untouched=input_from_the_user` _doesn't_ copy the object `input_from_the_user` refers to. This essentially creates a new pointer/reference to that object. Depending on what `input_from_the_user` is, you can try `matrix_untouched=input_from_the_user.copy()`

Comment: If `.copy()` doesn't work, you can use the [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) command.